# XML Sorting used LINQ in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, xml, linq, view, controller

I am trying to get sorting working for certain columns from an xml file. Here is what I have.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        IEnumerable<Personal> personals;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        List<Personal> persons = new List<Personal>();
        doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Matt.Dodson\\Desktop\\SampleWork\\PersonsApplicationFromXMLFile\\PersonsApplicationFromXMLFile\\DAL\\Personal.xml");
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("/Persons/record"))
        {
            persons.Add(new Personal
            {
                ID = node["ID"].InnerText,
                Name = node["Name"].InnerText,
                Email = node["Email"].InnerText,
                DateOfBirth = node["DateOfBirth"].InnerText,
                Gender = node["Gender"].InnerText,
                City = node["City"].InnerText
            });
        }
        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "ID":
                personals = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.ID);
                break;
            case "Name":
                personals = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.Name);
                break;
            case "City":
                personals = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.City);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return View(persons);
    }
```

Things I've tried include .getElementByTagName("ID").toString().OrderBy(...), to no avail. I'm pretty sure I've got syntax all wrong.
Please help and thank you.

Comment: personals != persons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to let the was sorted collection result set to  `persons` otherwise, the collection wasn't ordered by.

```
switch (sortOrder)
{
    case "ID":
        persons = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.ID).ToList();
        break;
    case "Name":
        persons = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.Name).ToList();
        break;
    case "City":
        persons = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.City).ToList();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
return View(persons);
```

---

I would use `linq` instead of `foreach` let the code more clear.

`SelectNodes("/Persons/record").Cast<XmlNode>()` use `Cast<XmlNode>()` let `XmlNodeList` to `IEnumerable<XmlNode>` collection then use 
linq `select`.

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load("C:\\Users\\Matt.Dodson\\Desktop\\SampleWork\\PersonsApplicationFromXMLFile\\PersonsApplicationFromXMLFile\\DAL\\Personal.xml");
    IEnumerable<Personal> persons = doc.SelectNodes("/Persons/record")
        .Cast<XmlNode>()
        .Select(node => new Personal()
        {
            ID = node["ID"].InnerText,
            Name = node["Name"].InnerText,
            Email = node["Email"].InnerText,
            DateOfBirth = node["DateOfBirth"].InnerText,
            Gender = node["Gender"].InnerText,
            City = node["City"].InnerText
        });
    switch (sortOrder)
    {
        case "ID":
            persons = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.ID);
            break;
        case "Name":
            persons = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.Name);
            break;
        case "City":
            persons = persons.OrderBy(Personal => Personal.City);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return View(persons.ToList());
}
```

Comment: That just gave me another error, taking it out of context(List)

Comment: @MathewDodson you just add `.ToList()`, because I think your view need to use `List<Personal>` type

Comment: Now it's giving me 'use of unassigned local variable, personals'. Trying everything.

Comment: @MathewDodson I edit my answer and add another solution I think is better way.

Comment: Or just `return View(personals)`

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it worked like a charm. I don't think that lists and ienums are interchangeable. I'm bad at syntax. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need return personals

```
...
return View(personals);
```